# Django Celery delay() always pushing to default 'celery' queue

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm ripping my hair out with this one.

The crux of my issue is that, using the Django `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` setting in my `settings.py` is not forcing my tasks to go to that particular queue that I've set up. It always goes to the default `celery` queue in my broker.

However, if I specify `queue=proj:dev` in the `shared_task` decorator, it goes to the correct queue. It behaves as expected.

My setup is as follows:

- Django code on my localhost (for testing and stuff). Executing task `.delay()`'s via Django's shell (`manage.py shell`)
- a remote Redis instance configured as my broker
- 2 celery workers configured on a remote machine setup and waiting for messages from Redis (On Google App Engine - irrelevant perhaps)

*NB: For the pieces of code below, I've obscured the project name and used `proj` as a placeholder.*

`celery.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery, shared_task

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY', force=True)

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

`settings.py`

```
...
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:{}@{}:6379/0'.format(
    os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
    os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'alice-redis-vm'))
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = os.environ.get('CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE', 'proj:dev')
```

The idea is that, for right now, I'd like to have different queues for the different environments that my code exists in: dev, staging, prod. Thus, on Google App Engine, I define an environment variable that is passed based on the individual App Engine service.

#### Steps

So, with the above configuration, I fire up the shell using `./manage.py shell` and run `add.delay(2, 2)`. I get an `AsyncResult` back but Redis monitor clearly shows a message was sent to the default `celery` queue:

```
1497566026.117419 [0 155.93.144.189:58887] "LPUSH" "celery"
...
```

What am I missing?

Not to throw a spanner in the works, but I feel like there was a point today at which this was actually working. But for the life of me, I can't think what part of my brain is failing me here.

Stack versions:

- `python`: 3.5.2
- `celery`: 4.0.2
- `redis`: 2.10.5
- `django`: 1.10.4

Comment: Hi Kyle, are you sure CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE is a supported setting for redis backend? From the docs, it's only listed under the AMQP Backend Settings section. For the case you specified, you can probably make do with specifying different db's for each environment. e.g., 0=dev, 1=staging, 2=production

Comment: @e4c5 I'll take that bet. It would default to 'proj:dev' if the env lacked it. The second value of os.environ.get is the default if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Kyle make sure you have defined `proj:dev` in your `CELERY_QUEUES` setting.

Comment: @e4c5 - so `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` is a constant. It will be set by an envvar also called `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEU` (consistency FTW). However, Robin is right, it will simply default to `proj:dev`. However, despite the default, my messages aren't going to `proj:dev`

Comment: @hurturk - that is missing, I'll add some config, try it out again and update the question if necessary, thanks!

Comment: @RobinAnupol - the idea of using different DBs is not a bad one, actually. The only thing I don't like about the numerical  'index' is the lack of clear connection to a particular environment. It's very easy to read `proj:dev`, `proj:staging` etc... and know exactly what you're looking at. But, it's definitely worth a shot. 

As to the support CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE for Redis - is that a consideration? I thought that Celery would simply use that as the 'key' in Redis, to which it pushes the task. Are you thinking perhaps Celery doesn't support the concept with using Redis as a broker?

Comment: @RobinAnupol - out of interest, where did you see that CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE is only a setting for the AMQP backend? I'm looking at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#message-routing

This seems to suggest some general task routing settings.

Some more information here - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#routing-changing-default-queue

Comment: I also thought it was only for AMQP but I have checked source code, `routes.py` also [use](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c122150887ae3633ff0164a5670d23bd093354e4/celery/app/routes.py#L73) that.

Comment: @hurturk RobinAnupol - thanks guys. I've left the answer here in case you're interested. Turns out, inconsistent documentation.

Comment: @KyleO'Brien admittedly it's to an old version of the documentation (3.1) here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-default-queue It's the first hit when you google CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE. Congrats on solving it man! Btw I would still go for different DBs if I were you -- perhaps in addition to the default queue setting. If you end up using Redis as a cache (as I do) or some sort of store as well, it's easy to make a mistake but very hard to debug. I might just be overly cautious though. In fact, we opted for different Redis instances for each env.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is far more simple than I thought - incorrect documentation!!

The Celery documentation asks us to use `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` to set the `task_default_queue` configuration on the celery object.

Ref: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

We should currently use `CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE`. This is an inconsistency in the naming of all the other settings' names. It was raised on Github here - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3772

#### Solution summary

Using `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` in a configuration module (using `config_from_object`) has no effect on the queue.

Use `CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE` instead.

Comment: TIL celery configuration is lowercase mapping from all variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here because you're trying to implement a predefined queue using SQS in Celery and find that Celery creates a new queue called "celery" in SQS regardless of what you say, you've reached the end of your journey friend.

Before passing `broker_transport_options` to Celery, change your default queue and/or specify the queues you will use explicitly. In my case, I need just the one queue so doing the following worked:

```
celery.conf.task_default_queue = "<YOUR_PREDEFINED_QUEUE_NAME_IN_SQS">
```